# Integrate inmobi and Millennial Media SDK's

Tags: ios, admob, inmobi

I have successfully integrated Admob SDK.

Now I also want to implement **inmobi** and **Millennial Media ads** in my project.

I am aware of the fact that inmobi and Millennial Media ads can be controlled via **Admob Mediation**.

But to show the inmobi and Millennial Media ads, do I have to integrate their SDK's separately or I can just show these ads using **Admob Mediation** ?

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For Integrating InMobi ads with AdMob Mediation Follow steps as:

- Login into your AdMob account, click on Sites and App and select Ad Network Mediation.

  - Add **Network Mediation Placement** and add **InMobi Ad Network** to the mediation 
    placement.
- For this **InMobi "App Id"** is required. So Login into the InMobi 
  account and under "**My Properties**" take "**App Id**" of one your property for which you 
  want mediation.
- After successfully adding InMobi under AdMob Ad Network Mediation assign eCPM to InMobi.
- Download Inmobi sdk and adapter from following link
  https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation-networks
- Add InMobi sdk and Adapter to your code
- Specify your Mediation ID instead of your AdMob site ID as the adUnitID of your 
  GADBannerView. Your Mediation ID can be found on the AdMob Ad Network Mediation settings 
  page of the mediation placement you’ve created.

  From here follow normal procedure of loading the ad using AdMob Sdk and the InMobi ads will 
  be fetched from as per the mediation rule created in the AdMob account.

Comment: Should I use inmobi propertyId OR slot id as appId in admob mediation?

Answer (score 4):

Essentialy, AdMob acts as a "mediation service". "Adapter libraries" transforms load requests of AdMob to requests for InMobi and MillenialMedia and potentially other ad networks.

These ad networks build the adapter files for you; so just copying the adapter library, along with the adnetwork library, the integration should work out of the box. No additional coding is required from your end.

This being said, if you wanted to use advanced features of a particular ad network, additional parameters could be passed to ad mob, which would then be given to the respective ad network (check out integration guidelines for more details). However, this is advanced integration and most developers do not use these except in extreme debugging and integrating situations.

A list of adnetworks and adapters can be found at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation-networks

-Akshay, SDK developer, InMobi

Comment: So you mean to say I need to add library of inmobi and MillenialMedia ?

Comment: Yes. Thats right. You need to copy 1. Library of InMobi, MillenialMedia; 2. Adapter files for InMobi, MillenialMedia; and that's it. Please mark answered if this helps. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have added all the libraries and adapter files. Do I have to use **admob mediation key** instead of **admob key** now?

Comment: Also can you suggest me how can we track if in my app is really showing inmobi and millennial media ads ?

Comment: @Akshay, I am saying the same thing, I mean you don't have to install individual SDK for individual network integration. Admob SDK & adapter library manages automatically.

Comment: You will have to use mediation key. You will also need set up the network parameters. For example, you will need to create an InMobi account and create a "site-id". Then in your slot configuration in AdMob mediation, you will have to give InMobi's site-id (also known as app-id). Tracking, reporting and configurations need to be setup in your admob dashboard. You can contact admob for more help.

Answer (score -3):

> No, you don't need to integrate the Sdk Separately. Admob sdk
>   automatically manages it.